# How do I set my Feedburner feed to use my favicon?

Tags: feedburner, favicon

I'm not sure if this setting is handled in my wordpress installation or by Feedburner but right now my feedburner feed is displaying the feedburner favicon.  How can I set it to use my blogs favicon?

Comment: Displaying where exactly? I don't think favicon is part of RSS specification at all.

Comment: This is not a WordPress question. Feedburner is a third party application and is not even locally hosted.

Comment: @John - I realize that it's not locally hosted but it populates the feeds with information from Wordpress so it followed that it would also pull the favicon from some setting in wordpress.

Comment: @Rarst - For one, on my feedburner feed site.  Two, there are a number of places that pull feeds and display them along with their favicon.  For example portfo.li for some reason is displaying the Feedburner favicon for my site dispite showing the correct one for other sites that are also using Feedburner.  If the favicon is not part of the RSS specs at all then it's apparently not a wp issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Rarst pointed out, there is no implementation of a favicon in the RSS spec (although there does [seem to be one for Atom](http://atomenabled.org/developers/syndication/#optionalFeedElements)).

Feedburner (and other readers) rely on the de-facto standard that the favicon exists at the website root;

```
http://example.com/favicon.ico
```

Some clients may also try `.png` or `.gif`, but your safest bet is the standard `.ico`.

- [How to get your favicon working with Feedburner](http://www.vreference.com/2009/11/24/fellow-bloggers-how-to-get-your-favicon-working-with-feedburner/)
- [Favicons for XML/RSS feeds](http://ask.metafilter.com/83568/Favicons-for-xmlrss-feeds)
- [Wikipedia Favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Feedburner looks for a favicon in a directory that doesn't exist. Wordpress is simply using the blog name as an alias.